# Software to improve locating stuff in a house

Tags: windows, android, game, desktop-environment, augmented-reality

I am looking for a software product that emulates a house full of stuff. The stuff can be hidden in holes, containers, below our behind doors, and gets displaced daily.

The player or given stuff to find, or, perhaps, even stuff to do (with the stuff).

The player has to find the stuff and carry out the tasks quickly.

The better the player gets, the more points to player makes.

Where can I find such a software, for PC, tablet, or mobile phone.

Someone i know has an app called "criminal case", on Android, which would be a very basic version of what I'm asking for, except for the stuff is always in the same place, and you can only view a room at a time (no OpenGL), and you're not required to do or carry out tasks with the stuff.

I'm trying to improve my searching and finding and doing and where to look for and spatial awareness skills.

I think such an app would be very useful for this.

Perhaps there's even a version developed for AR glasses.

Anyone that knows a similar software, that does what I'm asking for, would be off great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Did you find anything?

Comment: No, not yet. Would be great if we could have something.